# Objective-c error with subclass not finding superclass interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I've been working on an app that uses a collection view, and I'm creating a custom view cell (Category View Cell) which is a subclass of UICollectionViewCell. I also wanted to create a subclass of the custom view cell (LinkCell). I've been searching for a while now and I cannot find why I am getting the error "Cannot find interface declaration of 'CategoryViewCell', superclass of 'LinkCell'"

```
//CategoryViewCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface CategoryViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

@property (nonatomic) ViewController *parentView;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *cellName;

@end
//CategoryViewCell.m
#import "CategoryViewCell.h"

@implementation CategoryViewCell

@end

//LinkCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CategoryViewCell.h"
#import "PJP Webview.h"

@interface LinkCell : CategoryViewCell //Error here

@property (nonatomic) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *password;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *urlToLink;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *urlToLinkS;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *urlToLinkP;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *urlToLinkT;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *body;

-(IBAction)celltapped:(id)sender;

@end
//LinkCell.m
#import "LinkCell.h"

@implementation LinkCell

@synthesize urlToLink, username, password, image, cellName, parentView;

-(IBAction)celltapped:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *launchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hasLaunched%@Before", self.cellName];
    BOOL hasLaunchedCellBefore = [userDefaults boolForKey:launchString];
    if (!hasLaunchedCellBefore) {
        // first time launch code

        hasLaunchedCellBefore = TRUE;
        [userDefaults setBool:hasLaunchedCellBefore forKey:launchString];
        [userDefaults synchronize];

        PJP_Webview *vc = [parentView.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];
        vc.currentCell = self;
        [parentView presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {

    }
}

@end
```

Could someone please show me where my error is?

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project folder (cmd+shift+k)? then building again.

Comment: @Joshua, yes I have, and when I clean it the error goes away, but as soon as I build it the error comes back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it; ViewController.h uses the CategoryViewCell and I imported the .h and used the @class for the ViewController property on CategoryViewCell.h. Only the @class was necessary; I guess some sort of circular dependency was created. The weird part was that CategoryViewCell.h didn't have the errors, its subclass did. Thanks to anyone who answered!

Answer (score 0):

Choose file CategoryViewCell.m and check it's added to target or not.

[image]

Comment: Header files are not added to targets.

Comment: @Proton, sorry for the delayed response. The CategoryViewCell.m does have the target membership selecting the project target. It still does not work though.

Comment: I just solved it; ViewController.h uses the categoryviewcell and i imported the .h and used the @class for the ViewController property. Only the class was necessary.